# Subquery returns more than 1 row in MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on db in MySQL and need data from few tables in one row. It's problem connected with relative databases:

```
CREATE TABLE pet (id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
insert into pet values (1,"Rufus");
insert into pet values (2,"Bali");
insert into pet values (3,"Lolo");

CREATE TABLE own (id INT, own_name VARCHAR(20), own_color VARCHAR(20));
insert into own values (1,"Me", "Red");
insert into own values (2,"Other owners" ,"Green");

CREATE TABLE pet_owner (id INT, id_pet INT, id_own INT);
insert into pet_owner values (1, 1, 1);
insert into pet_owner values (2, 2, 1);
insert into pet_owner values (3, 3, 2);

DROP procedure if exists `pet`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure `pet`() 
BEGIN
set @param = 1;
select
a.own_color as 'color',
(select id_pet from pet_owner where id_own = @param) as 'pets'

from own as a where a.id = @param;
END$$

call pet;
```

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

How to collect all pets id's in one row (every id_pet can be in other column)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the stored proc is intended to do, or the format of the output you are expecting from the query within it. There is no correlation between the main query and the subquery at present - is that intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `group_concat()`:

```
select o.own_color as color,
       (select group_concat(id_pet) from pet_owner po where po.id_own = @param) as pets
from own o
where o.id = @param;
```

Note that I made a couple of changes to the query:

- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table name, instead of useless letters (`o` for owners, instead of `a`).
- The column aliases are not surrounded by single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  If you must escape identifiers, use double quotes or backticks.
- Added the `group_concat()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
-- ...
select
a.own_color as 'color',
(select group_concat(id_pet,',') from pet_owner where id_own = @param) as 'pets'
from own as a where a.id = @param;
```

but beware that there is a 1024 byte limit on result. to solve this run this query before your query: (change the 2048 according to your needs) .

```
set group_concat_max_len=2048
```

Comment: i may answer late , but he was . in addition i put the memory limit tip